# How to create a javascript API with asynchronous calls?

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous, callback

I am a beginner in javascript OOP. I'm trying to make an API to provide information stored in database. I didn't specifically used to use callbacks.

My constructor makes an asynchronous call (get_question function) so when I want to use my API :

```
var obj = new API('id');
obj.get_description();
```

my object is empty because there is no synchronization !

**So,how to create a usable API in this way knowing that my constructor makes an asynchronous call?**

Here is the code of my API class:

```
var API = function(question_id_algo) {
    var id_algo = question_id_algo;
    var self = this;
    var question_object = null;

    this.callback_db_init = function(data) {
        question_object = data;
    }

    get_question(id_algo, self.callback_db_init);

    this.get_description = function() {
        if(question_object != null){
            return question_object.description;
        }
    }
}
```

And my get_question function

```
function get_question(id_algo, callback_function)
{
    Lungo.Data.Sql.select('question', {id_algo: id_algo}, callback_function);
}
```

I use [Lungo.js](http://lungo.tapquo.com/howto/data/) framework to access my SQLite database.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: @Pointy, I guess we need to run that `get_question()` function to get the question ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get a synchronous result from an asynchronous operation. Something here must take a callback: either the constructor or the accessor function. Placing it on the constructor probably makes the most sense (though it may vary, depending on your exact program structure):

```
var obj = new API('id', function() {
    // this function runs when the API object is ready
    this.get_question();
});
```

The code to achieve this would look like:

```
var API = function(question_id_algo, constructorArgCallback) {
    //...
   var apiObj = this;

    this.callback_db_init = function(data) {
        question_object = data;
        constructorArgCallback.call(apiObj);
    }

    //...
}
```